# how to handle event click the custom button on toolbar of Ckeditor in Angular 2 Rc1?

Tags: angular, ckeditor

I added a new button on my toolbar , by using this code :

**demo.html**

```
<ck-editor>ckeditor_inst_1</ck-editor>
```

**demo.ts**

```
import {
  Component,
  Inject,
  OnInit,
  ElementRef,
  Renderer,
  ViewQuery,
  ViewChild,
  AfterContentInit
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ck-editor',
  template: ''
})

class CKEditor {
  constructor(_elm: ElementRef) {
    CKEDITOR.replace(_elm.nativeElement);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'demo',
  templateUrl: 'client/dev/demo/demo.html'
})

export class DemoComponent implements OnInit,AfterContentInit {
  constructor(){
  }

   CreateUploadImageCkeditor(){
    CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.ui.addButton('Hello',
      {
        label: 'Upload Image',
        command: 'uploadImage',
        icon: window.location.href +'/uploads/Up.png'
      });

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.CreateUploadImageCkeditor();
  }

}
```

I want to do something when a user clicks my custom button . How do I handle an event click on my custom button? Thank you for any help .

Comment: Why Rc1 and not RC4?

Comment: @AngJobs what difference ? if I use Rc4 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more related to CKEditor than Angular2. Nonetheless:

1. Add `NgZone` to your constructor

   ```
   class CKEditor {
       constructor(private _zone: NgZone, _elm: ElementRef) {
           CKEDITOR.replace(_elm.nativeElement);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Create the button:

   ```
   editorInstance.ui.addButton('MyButton', {
       label: 'My Button',
       command: 'mycommand',
       toolbar: 'basicstyles'
   });
   ```

   The important thing is the command name `mycommand`.
3. Create the command. This gets called when you click the button:

   ```
   editorInstance.addCommand('mycommand', {
       exec: (editor) => {
           this._zone.run(() => {
               // Your Angular code goes here.
           });
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: I use your code and it's console this error .
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'run' of undefined"

Comment: I updated my answer. There was `function` keyword that you probably don't want if you want to use parent closure with `_zone`